# Solving a differential equation with sines and cosines

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve a differential equation which occurs in the proces of computing the following reduced Schrödinger equation by making use of a (Prüfer) transformation

$$
y''(x) = (V(x)-1)y(x) \, \, \quad x \in [0,1]
$$

with $y(0)=0$, $y(1)=0$, $V(x)=x^2$. The transformation goes as
$$
y = \rho \sin(\theta(x)) \, \, \quad z = \rho \cos(\theta(x)).
$$

The second order Schrödinger equation can also be written as

$$
\begin{cases}
y' = z  \\
z' = (V(x)-1)y = (x^2-1)y
\end{cases}
$$

By differentiating $y$ and $z$ from the transformation and combining the two first order differential equations, we get the following differential equation in $\theta$
$$
\theta'(x) = \cos(\theta(x))^2 + (1-x^2)\sin(\theta(x))^2.
$$

With a better notation, this becomes
$$
y'(x) = \cos(y(x))^2+(1-x^2)\sin(y(x))^2
$$
The problem is that I don't know how to solve this differential equation. Is there something wrong with the transformation itself?

Comment: but your equation is not solvable in the known elementary functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what it's worth, the solution to your ODE is:

$$y(x)=C_1\exp(-x^2/2)+C_2\exp(-x^2/2)\mbox{erfi}(x),$$

where $\mbox{erfi}$ is [the imaginary error function.](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erfi.html) The solution is actually not entirely difficult to see. Your equation is homogenous and you're looking for two linearly independent solutions. If you can guess that $\exp(-x^2/2)$, is a solution, then the other one is of the form $v(x)\exp(-x^2/2)$.